# What are possible states of remote computer after power outage?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nfs, system-recovery

I have remote computer to whos LAN I have full access. After a power outage, I can only ping this computer, but can't `ssh` to it.

Nmap shows the following picture:

```
Host is up (0.00055s latency).
Not shown: 998 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
111/tcp  open  rpcbind
2049/tcp open  nfs
```

I have also access to this computer's power supply. If I turn it of, ping disappears. After I turn it on, after many minutes ping appears back, then, after several minutes, `rpcbind` appears and then, after even more minutes, `nfs` appears.

Given this information, is it possible to deduce, in which state this computer is?

Is it possible to recover it remotely? What else can be diagnosed remotely?

If on site, what is the simplest way to recover it given it is headless?

Linux version on it was Ubunti 18.04 LTS.

Comment: If you've got remote access to the power strip, I'm astounded you don't have access to an IPMI management card. Well worth the investment for remote systems

Comment: @roaima I didn't find good solution for this

Comment: @gapsf мы знакомы?